# Double Columns for Problems

Tags: spacing

I am working on a calculus `pdf` and I am writing a small section of text which contains problems for the reader to solve. I want the problems to be of two columns to use up all the space I have. An example of this is shown in H. Jerome Keisler's *Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach* at page 15:

[image: Example of Double Column]

However, I came across a few problems while trying to do this. My first attempt at creating double column problems was with the `\hfill` command. With this command, I programmed

```
\large\textbf{Exercises for 1.1}

\normalsize
(1) Identify if the following numbers are real.
\begin{changemargin}{1cm}{1cm} 
(1a) $7$ \hfill (1b) $2\pi$ \\
(1c) $6/0$ \hfill (1d) $4$ \\
\end{changemargin}
```

which created a problem:

[image: \hfill failed]

With `\hfill`, the problems are aligned to the right margin.

Later, I came across the `multicol` package. With this package, I programmed

```
\large\textbf{Exercises for 1.1}

\normalsize
(1) Identify if the following numbers are real.
\begin{changemargin}{1cm}{1cm} 
\begin{multicols}{2}
(1a) $7$  (1b) $2\pi$ \\
(1c) $6/0$  (1d) $4$ \\
\end{multicols}
\end{changemargin}
```

which gave:

[image: \multicol failed]

What is a (preferably) lightweight solution to my problem?

Comment: Welcome to  TeX SX! Three packages are designed for such things: `shortlst`, `tablists`  and `tasks`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As told in comments, `tasks` can be used for this job. Here is a sample.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[more]{tasks}
\NewTasks[style=enumerate,counter-format=tsk[1].,label-format=\bfseries,label-width=2.6ex,column-sep=2ex,before-skip=2pt,
      item-indent = {1em}]{problems}[\problem](2)
\begin{document}
  Solve these problems
  \begin{problems}
    \problem $x= y+z$
    \problem $x^n= y^n+z^n$
    \problem $x= y+z$
    \problem $x^n= y^n+z^n$
    \problem* This is some sample text we will use to create a somewhat longer text
        spanning a few lines.
   \problem $x= y+z$
    \problem $x^n= y^n+z^n$
  \end{problems}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I experience some problems with the `tasks` package. The lines are very spaced out, and it makes the examples look terrible.

Comment: @user3502615 You can adjust these: `,before-skip=-6pt,after-skip=-6pt,after-item-skip=-2pt` in `\NewTasks[style=enumerate,counter-format=tsk[1].,label-format=\bfseries,label-width=2.6ex,column-sep=2ex,before-skip=2pt,
      item-indent = {1em},before-skip=-6pt,after-skip=-6pt,after-item-skip=-2pt]{problems}[\problem](2)`. These parameters are documented in `tasks` user manual.

Answer (score 2):

By using `multicols` you were on the right way. For example, you can simply place an `enumerate` environment inside:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{Exercise}[title={Test}, label={testex}]

        \lipsum[2]

        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, labelsep=*, align=left, label=\theExercise(\alph*)]
                \item $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
                \item $E = mc^2$
                \item $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
                \item $E = mc^2$                
                \item $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
                \item $E = mc^2$                
                \item $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
                \item $E = mc^2$                
                \item $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
                \item $E = mc^2$            
                \item $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$
                \item $E = mc^2$
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}

    \end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mikasa Thanks for your kind words! <3

Comment: I meant it because i am preparing a book full of math exercises.

Comment: can i insert something like `\section(\alph*)` inside options to enumerate items like 1(1),1(2)... automatically?

Comment: @Mikasa If you have a follow-up question, best use the "Ask Question" button on the top right. More people will see your question and able to help you.

Comment: Thanks in advance. I'll do it. I have thought of it.

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  Solve these problems
  \begin{align*}
  1. \;\; &   x= y+z & 2.\;\; &x^n= y^n+z^n \\    
   3.\;\; &  x= y+z &  4.\;\;  & x^n= y^n+z^n \\ 
    \end{align*}


{\bf  This is some sample text we will use to create a somewhat longer text
    spanning a few lines.}

    \begin{align*}
   5.\;\; &  x= y+z & 6.\;\; & x^n= y^n+z^n\\    
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```